# Rails - How to calculate "you beat xx% of users on score"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say I have a user model:

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    end
```

and an answer model:

```
    class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user

    end
```

To encourage users to give out more answers, I want to show for a specific user what is his/her rank in all users. (Ranking is based on the number of answers he/she gives out)

I don't want to create a ranking board due to privacy issue. I only want to return a message of "you beat xx% of users in the number of answers given out".

I have a rough idea that is to do a group by and get the rank number for this user, but I am not sure how should I make it as efficient as possible.

Comment: Show what you've tried, and someone can suggest improvements. Although that's probably more appropriate for codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def answered_percentile
    user_answer_count = answers.count
    less = User.all.map {|u| u.answers.count}.select {|e| e < user_answer_count}.count
    100 * less / User.count
  end
end

u = User.find(42)
puts "you beat #{u.answered_percentile}% of users in the number of answers given out"
```